# How to overwrite $_canCapture and $_canCapturePartial for COD payment method?

Tags: magento-1.9

These varibles are defined in an abstract class. I found them at app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php. Since the classs is abstract, I couldn't do anything as it would interfere with other payment menthods. I need to create a module to overwrite the Cashondelivery.php.

**What I have tried so far?**
I tried to created a module extending the Cashondelivery.php since I want to rewrite these variables only for cod payment method. Alexandre have demonstrated what I need to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242058/magento-create-unpaid-invoice-programmatically) for Bank Transfer Method.

*This is my first time creating a module please be gentle* *Here's the code*

```
class My_codinvoicer_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery
{
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
}
```

Comment: Mind showing any research effort from your side? Rather than just asking for code?

Comment: This is the research [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242058/magento-create-unpaid-invoice-programmatically) Little help won't harm :)